# Function Variable Number of Arguments plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, functions

I am looking to do a function with non fixed number of arguments like decode function.
The syntax for the `DECODE` function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )
```

I want to do the same [] **for example**:

```
SUM(expresion1, expresion2, [expresion]...)
```

A practical result could be:

```
SELECT SUM(1,1) FROM dual;
SELECT SUM(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) FROM dual;
etc
```

Is that posible in PL/SQL or is this limited to Oracle built-in functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DECODE` is an SQL function, not PL/SQL. You can not use it in plain PL/SQL, only as part of SQL statements.

There is no nice and easy way for this. There is the method with collections, for example:

```
create or replace type t_numbers as table of number;
/

create or replace function sum_plsql (p_numbers t_numbers) return number
as
  rv number := 0;
begin
  for n in 1..p_numbers.count
  loop
    rv := rv + p_numbers(n);
  end loop;
  return rv;
end;
/
```

Then:

```
select sum_plsql(t_numbers(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) from dual;

9
```

There are built-in, non-documented simple list types, so you do not need to define your own types at all circumstances, but relying on non-documented features is generally bad practice, as they may change in newer versions without warning.

If there is a reasonable limit for the number of arguments:

```
create or replace function sum_plsql2 (p1 number default 0, p2 number default 0, p3 number default 0, p4 number default 0) return number
as
begin
  return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
end;
/

select sum_plsql2(1, 1, 1) from dual;

3
```

Obviously, these are neither tidy nor effective.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing that I know is to overload a function...

```
create or replace package test_pkg
as
    function variableParams ( a in varchar2, z in integer, y in integer ) return integer;
    function variableParams ( a in varchar2, z in integer, y in integer, x in integer ) return integer; 
end;
/

create or replace package body test_pkg
as
function variableParams
    (   a  in varchar2,
        z  in integer,
        y  in integer
    )
return integer
as  
    result integer;
begin
    if ( action = 'SUM' )
    then
        result := z + y;
    elsif ( action = 'SUBTRACT' )
    then
        result := z - y;
    else
        raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid action specified');
    end if;

    return result;
end variableParams;
function variableParams
    (   a  in varchar2,
        z  in integer,
        y  in integer,
        x  in integer
    )
return integer
as  
    result integer;
begin
    if ( action = 'SUM' )
    then
        result := z + y + x;
    elsif ( action = 'SUBTRACT' )
    then
        result := z - y - x;
    else
        raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid action specified');
    end if;

    return result;
end variableParams;
end test_pkg;
/
```

I like [Balazs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp) answer as well. Either way, I hope you aren't trying to allow too many elements because this could get messy.  :)

Good luck.