# In Oracle 12c, is there an alternative to CREATE TYPE when I only have read-only privileges?

Tags: oracle-12c, functions

I have read-only access to a Oracle 12c system where there is zero chance I can get additional privileges or get the DBAs to change anything on my behalf (such as do CREATE TYPEs for me).

I'm using Oracle 12c feature `WITH FUNCTION myfunc() .. SELECT ..` to create functions as part of my SQL queries, which is working great.

Except, I would like to do something similar as shown in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137256), which is:
`WITH FUNCTION myfunc(p_numbers t_numbers) .. SELECT ..`
where `t_numbers` would normally be declared:
`CREATE TYPE t_numbers AS TABLE OF NUMBER;`
which I can't do.

Is there any alternative way to accomplish this kind of "inline" function without `CREATE TYPE` privileges?  I want to be able to pass in an arbitrary quantity of numbers to an inline function as discussed in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137256).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is built-in type called `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` which is a `VARRAY(32767) of NUMBER`, and `EXECUTE` privilege is granted on it to everyone (`PUBLIC`). You can use that for up to 32767 numbers, example:

```
with function f1 (p_numbers SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) return number
as
begin
 return p_numbers.count;
end;
select f1(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) from dual;
/

F1(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
-------------------------------------
                                    7
```

In 19c, there is another built-in type called `SYS.FI_NUMERICALS` which is a `TABLE of NUMBER`, also usable by anyone in a similar way.

```
with function f1 (p_numbers SYS.FI_NUMERICALS) return number
as
begin
 return p_numbers.count;
end;
select f1(SYS.FI_NUMERICALS(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) from dual;
/

F1(SYS.FI_NUMERICALS(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
------------------------------------
                                   7
```

I have not found any documentation or reference for the latter.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I found `ODCINUMBERLIST` documented in "Oracle Database Online Documentation Library, 12c Release 1 -> Database Data Cartridge Developer's Guide -> Extensibility Constants, Types, and Mappings".  There are some other similar `varray` types in there for those needing something other than numbers.  For those who want to reference a particular element in the `varray`, the syntax is `p_numbers(1)` for the first element.  You showing the `.count` was a nice bonus as that's good info for iterating the array.

Comment: SYS.ODCIGRANULELIST is twice bigger than SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST.